# How can I spot a talented freelance blogger?

Tags: outsourcing

For our eCommerce business, I'm writing a series of cosmetics tips & trends blog posts that tie into our products. Once I have a few up (about 8), I want to hire a freelancer online, ideally a girl/lady who's passionate about cosmetics, writes interestingly and can take decent photos (mobile is ok with me). She would then report to me and write certain number of blog articles weekly.

How can I spot a talented freelance blogger? What are red flags to avoid?

Comment: I've split the question into four parts: [i. Finding them](http://freelancing.stackexchange.com/questions/2366/freelance-bloggers-1-4-finding-them), [ii. Spotting good ones](http://freelancing.stackexchange.com/questions/2369/freelance-bloggers-2-4-spotting-good-ones), [iii. Compensation](http://freelancing.stackexchange.com/questions/2371/freelance-bloggers-3-4-compensation) & [iv. Management](http://freelancing.stackexchange.com/questions/2370/freelance-bloggers-4-4-employee-management)

Comment: Hey a20, one of your questions got a pretty good answer. However, these other posts largely have the same exact content. Is it possible to differentiate them a bit so people don't feel like they're answering the same questions? The more tailored these are, the better chances of a good answer. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

You can find good freelance bloggers on freelancer websites such as Elance, Freelancer or Fiverr. There are few things that you should keep in mind.

1. Ask for the lady to show her sample writing.
2. Confirm that the writings she has shared are actually written by her.
3. Her charges for writing for you.
4. Her experience on writing about this kind of topics.

I hope these 4 things will help you in finding the best writer.

Comment: “Ask for the lady to show her sample writing.” The lady?!?!

Answer (score 1):

A good writer (of any gender who is knowledgeable about the subject) will have samples of writing for you to read - hopefully on other blogs.

You need to be willing to pay a decent wage to the right writer. If you are only paying a pittance to someone, you aren't going to get anyone good. If your blog is in English, hiring a native speaker is going to give you better results, and wages in English-speaking countries are generally at the higher end of the global wage pool.

If you want to try someone out, and have them write an article for you, be willing to pay them for it, and not expect them to do it "on spec" (Like "I'll hire you if I like your custom sample that you wrote specifically for me on a subject of my choosing"). That is the ethical way to conduct business.