# How do I manage a remote freelance writer?

Tags: outsourcing

For our eCommerce business, I'm writing a series of cosmetics tips & trends blog posts that tie into our products. Once I have a few up (about 8), I want to hire a freelancer online, ideally a girl/lady who's passionate about cosmetics, writes interestingly and can take decent photos (mobile is ok with me). She would then report to me and write certain number of blog articles weekly.

This would be my first time hiring a freelance blogger/writer. How do I manage this person remotely to ensure good article pipeline, quality of content and employee happiness?

Comment: I've split the question into four parts: [i. Finding them](http://freelancing.stackexchange.com/questions/2366/freelance-bloggers-1-4-finding-them), [ii. Spotting good ones](http://freelancing.stackexchange.com/questions/2369/freelance-bloggers-2-4-spotting-good-ones), [iii. Compensation](http://freelancing.stackexchange.com/questions/2371/freelance-bloggers-3-4-compensation) & [iv. Management](http://freelancing.stackexchange.com/questions/2370/freelance-bloggers-4-4-employee-management)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The principal behind freelance workers is that they do not *want* to be managed by others and have chosen a career path which allows them to manage *themselves*.

If you hire a freelance writer, it is not your position to manage them as an employee. You can set expectations as to quality and guidelines for delivery time/method(s). However, beyond that the "happiness" of the freelancer is the freelancer's responsibility.

Remember, freelancers are *not* your employees. They are a hired specialist and should be treated as such. Treating a freelancer as if they were your "employee" will probably not go over well with many. Treat any freelancer as you would treat any specialist you use - mechanic, doctor, plumber, electrician, etc. Yes you can set expectations and control your attitude while dealign with them. But in terms of quality and delivery it's up to them to live up to the expectations you've set forth.

Comment: I want to add to this that I really appreciate it when people, especially employers, are frank about stuff. When they treat me like a peer more than a professional we often both get more out of it. This of course needs some time to grow and isn't great advice for a starting relationship.